# Variable losing value inside whereRaw query scope

Tags: eloquent, laravel-4, scope

I have a variable defined, $siteID. However, Laravel is losing its value inside the query and I get an error "Undefined variable: siteID"

```
$directoryExternalStats = DB::table('directories')
    ->leftJoin('citations', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('directories.id', '=', 'citations.directory_id')
            ->where( function($dirindustries) use($siteID){
                $dirindustries->whereRaw('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT directory_model_id FROM directory_model_industry)')
                      ->orWhereRaw('id IN 
                        (SELECT directory_model_id FROM directory_model_industry 
                                    (SELECT industry_id FROM industry_site WHERE site_id = '. $siteID .')
                ;
            });
    });
```

I am declaring the variable for use inside the query, but Laravel is not recognizing it. Changing the syntax to use a placeholder does not help.

I have tried including the variable in the first closure:

```
$directoryExternalStats = DB::table('directories')
    ->leftJoin('citations', function($join) use($siteID)
    {
```

in the second closure:

```
        $join->on('directories.id', '=', 'citations.directory_id')
            ->where( function($dirindustries) use($siteID){
```

and in both closures:

```
$directoryExternalStats = DB::table('directories')
    ->leftJoin('citations', function($join) use($siteID)
    {
        $join->on('directories.id', '=', 'citations.directory_id')
            ->where( function($dirindustries) use($siteID){
```

but I get an error regardless. With Jonas's help, I noticed that including the variable in both closures results in a *different* error message: "Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::where()"

Is this an instance of a Laravel bug as mentioned here:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18952
or 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5992
or 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5466

Or am I just committing a syntax error somewhere?

Comment: You have to include the variable in both closures: `function($join) use($siteID)`

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I should have mentioned that I tried that first, but to no avail. Although now that I try it again, I notice that the error message is different.

Comment: What's the new error message?

Comment: "Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::where()"
From various posts it appears that Laravel does not like having an OR clause in a join. There is a reference to a blog post that solved the issue, but the blog is no longer online.

Comment: Sounds like an issue that has been fixed in the more recent version of Laravel. Can you upgrade?

Comment: Okay. Working on that. It may take me a few days to figure all that out. :-)